# Can I write about a noun for which I have used "the" later in the text?

Tags: word-usage, definite-article

If I am writing this for the first time in an article -

> **The** associations between factor A and factor B were found to be normal.

Now, I had not discussed any thing about the type of associations that *the*  specifies before the quoted sentence. But if I write about the associations just after that sentence, in the very next line so that a reader can connect and understand, is it be correct to use *the*?
We are told to use *the* for a noun that has been already discussed.

Comment: Use it before. 

Comment: If the noun has been the subject of earlier discussion, the definite article **the** is licensed, but that is not the only situation that permits use of **the**.  You could also say "No abnormal associations between factor A and factor B were found."  Typically you would first mention that factor A and B are associated in several ways, unless that knowledge on the part of the reader is taken for granted.

Comment: So, I can't write ???

Comment: Please edit your example to include the other sentence as well so we can clearly see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed approach would be okay so long as you designed the next sentence to be very clearly explaining what’s going on. Something like “These associations include *blah*, *blah*, and *blah*.”  Here the immediate and explicit reoccurrence of *associations* resolves any temporary puzzlement your readers may have experienced from having encountered “the associations” and wondering, “Wait, **what** associations?”

But you should proceed with caution because starting a sentence with “The associations…” when those associations have yet to make an appearance in the discourse does violate a contract that native English-speaking readers will expect writers to abide by. So it would probably be better to either rework the sentence or to work some mention of your associations into the text coming before.

Comment: It that particular noun has not been discussed before but if that noun is a well-known thing ? Will that work ???

Comment: Yes. I’ve edited my answer to address that case.